# sums of two arrays using divide and conquer

Tags: divide-and-conquer

The problem requires divide and conquer method to find the C, sums of two n-size array A,B. For example, A = {1,3}, B = {2,4}, then C = {3,5,7}.

How can we find C in a way that is faster than brutal-force algorithm(n^2 in this case)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The way you sum your arrays (every possible sum ?), it looks like in the worst case your array has n^2 elements

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of divide and conquer is to divide the big problem into a number of small subproblems.

After we solved each of the subproblems, the big original problem could be solved. However, in this problem, though we could use divide and conquer to divide the first array into subarrays with size one at the base, we still needed to check the sum of every possible pairs of data to be put into the output array, i.e. with two arrays containing `{a,b,c,d}` and `{e,f,g,h}` you would still have to find the sum of `ae,af,ag,ah,be,bf...`so on.

Thus, I think there would be no big difference between the efficiency of brute force and the divide and conquer method as every combination would have to check either method. Hope this helps.